# ECB vs global vs cscope .. in emacs

Tags: emacs, global, cscope, emacs-ecb

I've mainly used cscope only to browse source code in emacs.

It's very hard to google what other people mainly use to browse source code.
Because ECB(emacs code browser) would come up fairly top due to the search term similarity(browse*)

I wonder what other skilled emacs users use for c/c++/objective-c source code browsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly use `ctags` & `gtags` for navigation in code + semantic's built-in navigation routines. But I work mostly with C/C++ code with some Java/Hadoop snippets

Answer (score 2):

I use GNU Global and Speedbar.

I wrote a [blog article](http://www.wolinlabs.com/blog/emacs.global.speedbar.html) about how to set it up and use it if you're interested in trying it...